# Is there a way to enable and disable Mouse Hover feature using a command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

There is a very useful feature in Windows that allows users to activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse pointer. (See the screenshot).

However, I'd like to use this feature only sometimes but there is no easy and quick way to turn it on and off. If there was a command line to enable and disable this feature, I could create two bat files to do just that with a single click. Can you help me on this one?

[image]